# Access remote IP address homepage remotely through webserver

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, webserver

Scenario:
My company network has a machines with dedicated IP address. When we enter each IP on our browser within the company network, it takes us to the machine diagnostic page. What i am trying to accomplish is to access these machines remotely from our webserver. I tried adding a link on our website with 10.116.192.5 and it obviously didnt take me to the machine because i was out of that network. Is there anyway i can access these IP on my office network through our website? 
I tried using cURL but that does not work with java applet. So i am trying to find an alternate solution to it.
Would using iframe work in this scenario?

Rephrasing the scenario: Trying to redirect our website URL to point to an internal IP address URL. So for instance, if a client types www.scada.example.net/userinfo on browser, this would redirect on the server side internally to x.x.x.x and display on the client side as www.scada.example.net/userinfo.

Comment: Ask IT to set up a VPN.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it has anything to do with Codeigniter.

Comment: Our webserver is codeigniter frameword.
I dont want this solution only for me, or we would be setup a VPN from home to office. We want everyone visiting the website be able to access those IP pages live.

Comment: Well unless you have a direct IP connection from the outside to each PC (NOT recommended) you won't be able to access them this way.

Comment: well i tried cURL and it did work. But cURL wont work with java applet. So i am certain it would work but dont know the right direction towards it. I just need a way to access a webpage through the webserver and not from the client side, as cURL did.

Comment: Is there a way i could screen shot the page on that IP address live and display it?